# Group By Matrix Transformation Removes Field - Need Help Including "buildingName"

Tags: grafana, dashboard

I am working on a dashboard using Grafana and encountered an issue with the groupingToMatrix transformation that seems to remove the "buildingName" field. The dashboard is designed to show AI vs Baseline comparisons, and I have a table visualization that includes various fields such as "BuildingId," "System," and "buildingName." However, when applying the groupingToMatrix transformation to create a matrix, the "buildingName" field disappears.
Without transformation:
[image: Without transformation]
With transformation:
[image: With transformation]
All I want to do is add buildingName field in that query below is the JSON, for some reason whenever the transformation is applied as you can see the field BuildingName disappears.

```
{
  "id": 9,
  "gridPos": {
    "h": 17,
    "w": 24,
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  },
  "type": "table",
  "title": "AI vs Baseline - $period days ",
  "transformations": [
    {
      "id": "calculateField",
      "options": {
        "alias": "temp1",
        "binary": {
          "left": "days$period",
          "operator": "-",
          "reducer": "sum",
          "right": "baseline$period"
        },
        "mode": "binary",
        "reduce": {
          "reducer": "sum"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "calculateField",
      "options": {
        "alias": "temp2",
        "binary": {
          "left": "temp1",
          "operator": "/",
          "reducer": "sum",
          "right": "baseline$period"
        },
        "mode": "binary",
        "reduce": {
          "reducer": "sum"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "calculateField",
      "options": {
        "alias": "aiVsBaseline",
        "binary": {
          "left": "temp2",
          "operator": "*",
          "reducer": "sum",
          "right": "100"
        },
        "mode": "binary",
        "reduce": {
          "reducer": "sum"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "organize",
      "options": {
        "excludeByName": {},
        "indexByName": {
          "aiVsBaseline": 8,
          "baseline90": 5,
          "buildingId": 2,
          "buildingName": 0,
          "companyName": 1,
          "days90": 4,
          "systemType/signalPositionType": 3,
          "temp1": 6,
          "temp2": 7
        },
        "renameByName": {
          "A · buildingId": "BuildingId",
          "A · systemType/signalPositionType": "System",
          "B · buildingId": "BuildingId",
          "aiVsBaseline": "",
          "buildingId": "BuildingId",
          "buildingName": "BuildingName",
          "systemType/signalPositionType": "System"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "groupingToMatrix",
      "options": {
        "columnField": "System",
        "rowField": "BuildingId",
        "valueField": "aiVsBaseline"
      },
      "disabled": true
    }
  ],
  "datasource": {
    "type": "yesoreyeram-infinity-datasource",
    "uid": "xxx"
  },
  "pluginVersion": "9.2.2",
  "description": "",
  "fieldConfig": {
    "defaults": {
      "custom": {
        "align": "center",
        "displayMode": "color-background",
        "inspect": false,
        "filterable": false
      },
      "mappings": [
        {
          "options": {
            "0": {
              "color": "#ffffff",
              "index": 2
            },
            "": {
              "color": "#808080",
              "index": 1,
              "text": "NO DATA"
            },
            "NaN": {
              "color": "#8c8b8b",
              "index": 0,
              "text": "NO DATA"
            }
          },
          "type": "value"
        }
      ],
      "thresholds": {
        "mode": "absolute",
        "steps": [
          {
            "color": "light-green",
            "value": null
          },
          {
            "color": "light-red",
            "value": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      "color": {
        "mode": "thresholds"
      },
      "decimals": 0,
      "noValue": "NO DATA",
      "unit": "percent"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "matcher": {
          "id": "byName",
          "options": "Cooling/Supply Temperature"
        },
        "properties": [
          {
            "id": "mappings",
            "value": [
              {
                "options": {
                  "": {
                    "color": "#808080",
                    "index": 3,
                    "text": "NO DATA"
                  },
                  "NaN": {
                    "color": "#808080",
                    "index": 0,
                    "text": "NO DATA"
                  }
                },
                "type": "value"
              },
              {
                "options": {
                  "from": 0,
                  "result": {
                    "color": "light-green",
                    "index": 1
                  },
                  "to": 100
                },
                "type": "range"
              },
              {
                "options": {
                  "from": -100,
                  "result": {
                    "color": "light-red",
                    "index": 2
                  },
                  "to": -0.001
                },
                "type": "range"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "matcher": {
          "id": "byName",
          "options": "BuildingId\\System"
        },
        "properties": [
          {
            "id": "color",
            "value": {
              "fixedColor": "#5b5c5b",
              "mode": "fixed"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "custom.width",
            "value": 268
          },
          {
            "id": "unit"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "matcher": {
          "id": "byName",
          "options": "BuildingName"
        },
        "properties": [
          {
            "id": "color",
            "value": {
              "mode": "fixed"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "custom.width",
            "value": 268
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "options": {
    "showHeader": true,
    "footer": {
      "show": false,
      "reducer": [
        "sum"
      ],
      "fields": "",
      "enablePagination": false
    },
    "frameIndex": 0,
    "sortBy": []
  },
  "targets": [
    {
      "columns": [],
      "computed_columns": [],
      "datasource": {
        "type": "xxx",
        "uid": "xxx"
      },
      "filters": [],
      "format": "table",
      "global_query_id": "",
      "groq": "*",
      "parser": "uql",
      "refId": "A",
      "root_selector": "$.aiVsBaseline.{\n    'signalPositionType': `signalPositionType`,\n    'systemType': `systemType`,\n    'days7':`days7`,\n    'days30': `days30`,\n    'days90': `days90`,\n    'baseline7': `baseline7`,\n    'baseline30': `baseline30`,\n    'baseline90': `baseline90`,\n    'buildingId': %.buildingId\n, 'builidingName': %.builidingName\n}",
      "source": "url",
      "type": "json",
      "uql": "parse-json\n| jsonata \"$.aiVsBaseline.{'companyName': %.companyName, 'buildingName': %.buildingName, 'buildingId': %.buildingId, 'systemType/signalPositionType': `systemType` & '/' & `signalPositionType`, 'days$period': `days$period`, 'baseline$period': `baseline$period`}\"\n\n",
      "url": "xxx",
      "url_options": {
        "body_content_type": "application/json",
        "body_form": [
          {
            "key": "buildingid",
            "value": "1145"
          }
        ],
        "body_type": "raw",
        "data": "",
        "method": "POST",
        "params": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```